# Add filter toolbar to advanecd search page

Tags: magento2, template, advanced-search, toolbar

How I can add filter toolbar to advanced search page.
I created **`catalog_category_view.xml`** and added the XML below but it does not change the template.

```
<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar">
    <block class="Plumrocket\ProductFilter\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
</referenceBlock>
<referenceBlock name="search_result_list">
    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok ...I did it
in this directory
`vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/layout`
copy catalogsearch_result_index.xml and past as talogsearch_advanced_result.xml
and in this directory `/backup/html/alotair/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout` copy catalogsearch_result_index.xml to catalogsearch_advanced_result.xml

it's worked for me . i know it is not a best solution then i wait for another developer